# How to hide a widget in a specific page on blogger?

Tags: xml, blogger

I'm trying to hide blog posts and sidebar in just one page of my blog. I researched on the internet and found this code:

```
 <b:if cond='data:blog.url != "http://mineoid.blogspot.com.tr/p/crafting.html"'>
...
 </b:if>
```

I added this code outside of blog posts and sidebar. Normally I use this code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != "static_page"'>
...
 </b:if>
```

And this code is working. But the first one doesn't. I want to hide those in just one page! Not all the pages. Are there anyone to fix this problem?

Comment: I tried the first snippet on a blogger template (with the link changed of course) and it worked as expected. Are you sure you're testing it correctly?

Comment: I did it. Don't worry. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot; p/crafting.html + &quot;'>
...
 </b:if>
```

Comment: Actually, I was looking for this code everywhere! Thanks a lot!